# Why can I see password prompts through redirecting output?

Tags: linux, ssh, redirection, stdout, stderr

So, I've got a command that I'm issuing that is essentially 'ssh'ing into various hosts:

```
 command 2&>1 | grep "desired output"
```

Every once in a while, in the midst of the command, it'll run into a host where I don't have my keys setup. When that happens, I get this output:

```
 Password:
```

Since I'm redirecting STDERR into STDOUT, then filtering STDOUT to only give me "desired output" (which doesn't include "Password:"), how is the password prompt being presented to me?

Comment: Also happens when using the Cisco anyconnect vpn CLI. You can pass in the password from a config file, but the password prompt will always get sent to the terminal. Until I found your question I thought I was going insane.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ssh opens /dev/tty for read and write to prompt for the password.

I guess this a security feature, the input has to be from the tty rather than stdin.

If you run `strace ssh <host>` strace will show you the system calls the command is making.

I get:

```
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)    = 4
...
write(4, "dave@host"..., 16dave's password: ) = 16
read(4,
```

Comment: From my understanding that's also the reason, why you can't simply pass the password to ssh from a script with a redirect. You'll need `expect` (http://expect.sourceforge.net and see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459182/using-expect-to-pass-a-password-to-ssh)

Comment: Terrific. I didn't think to dig in and strace it, since it was a passing curiosity, but thanks for that. I'm sure the knowledge will come in useful!

Comment: @terdon - the command you want (I think) is in the middle of the answer posted by parkydr: `strace ssh <host>`

Comment: @KevinFegan thanks, I know. The post has been edited since I posted my comment. Check the [editing log](http://superuser.com/posts/569437/revisions).